# Why ThreadAbortException when trying to close a SqlConnection in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I keep getting the following exception when I do:

```
Using cnn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionStr)
    cnn.Open()  'I am fine up to here'
End Using       'Here I am getting the following exception'
```

Manually called cnn.Dispose() causes the same exception. It seems to be OK in most places in my code but just in this one function I can't close the connection that I opened because I keep getting the ThreadAbortException. I am stumped, any ideas? any hints? Here is the exception I get:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosedPreviouslyOpened' threw an exception. ---> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' was thrown.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.CloseConnection(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.CloseConnection(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Close()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
```

Comment: `ThreadAbortException` is an asynchronous exception. Finding what raised it should be a fun challenge.

Comment: Where is this code running? ASP.NET, SQL Server?

Comment: This is a winForms app connecting to a SQL Server

Comment: Do you get the error if you call `cnn.Dispose` right after `cnn.Open`? If not, then this may point to something between the `cnn.Open` and `End Using` lines causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a dreaded "Finalize" method that someone put. It kept triggering and trying to close the connection. That was a couple of hours wasted!!! One day am going to get rid of all the Finalize methods in the code - until then - suck it up!

Comment: I always thought Finalize was a good thing? - try, catch, finally - as in, when finished with everything, close the database, even if an exception was thrown.  Although, probably not good when using *using* statements.

Comment: Nope that wasn't it - it just came back again... Was working just fine all day and then pow, it came back and won't stop!